# Debug error in Xamarin Forms (App is getting deployed in emulator)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build a Xamarin forms Application, It's a blank code, the code builds perfectly without error but it does not get deployed and debug on an emulator. It only deploys

If I click "Start without Debugging" then the application gets installed on my emulator or else it stays black and after building complete I get just a "Ready" output.

Can anyone help me with this? It started out of nowhere.

I tried to search for mono in "Extensions and Update" to enable it but couldn't find anything installed. If I try to install mono it gives an error "Either it is not compatible or already installed"

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

I need visual studio to build and display output in emulator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try to create a new emulator and run it again

Comment: @LeoZhu Tried, Not working. App deploys in emulator but not in debugging mode

Comment: Does the app run in non-debug mode ?

Comment: @neur0tic Yes it runs

Comment: 1. Go to project settings and check if the 'Debug' configuration selected and the conditional compilation symbols includes the `__DEBUG__` . 2.Completely uninstall the application from the emulator by going to Settings > Apps 3. Clean and rebuild.

Comment: You can also try `DEBUG` instead of `__DEBUG__`

Comment: @neur0tic Not working

Comment: I reinstalled visual studio, Now everything is working great